# filepond Jquery get file name that was dragged an dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, filepond

I am using jquery filepond image uploader plugin  that turns a file upload into a drag and drop zone.

```
                        <input  type="file" class="filepond" id="filepond"  
 name="filepond"/>
```

Below is the script that initialized file pond

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        // First register any plugins
        $.fn.filepond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview);

        // Turn input element into a pond
      $('.filepond').filepond();


        // Listen for addfile event
        $('.filepond').on('FilePond:addfile', function(e) {
            console.log('file added event', e);


        });


    });
    </script>
```

I have a  form that i plan to submit without using ajax it's a dircect form submit .

I just wanted to know how can i get the name of the file that was dragged and dropped  so  i can   allocate the file name value to another hidden input , so that i am able to submit the entire form directly via form submit.

I have console logged  the event once the file is dropped     console.log('file added event', e); .

Please help me  get the  file name  in file pond .

Comment: You can post the file name but you can't post the file data along with the form, unfortunately that's not possible due to a browser limitation. Do you only need the file name?

Comment: @Rik yah only the file name will store to database

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation you can use a [FilePond instace event FilePond:addfile](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-instance/#events) to know when a file has been dragged and dropped.

Inside the event then you can [get the file](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-instance/#getting-files) and then you just get the name with the [filename property](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/file/#properties).

Here is an example with plain javascript:

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);    
const pondBox = document.querySelector('.filepond--root');
pondBox.addEventListener('FilePond:addfile', e => {
        console.log('file added event', e.detail);
        var fileName = pond.getFile().filename;
    });
```

Comment: that solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: how we can get field name let suppose name is image1 or id image1